# ElasticSearch How to bulk update the timestamp field

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch, post, request

So when I pushed my data to an index, I made an error with timezone conversion. It was supposed to be UTC and instead was EST.

I have since corrected the error on my script, but the existing data still has incorrect timestamps.

I have tried one solution I found:

```
{ "query": { "match_all": {} }, "script": { "source": "ctx._source['@timestamp'] = OffsetDateTime.parse(ctx._source['@timestamp']).plusHours(5).toString()" } }
```

However I get an error here:

> "reason": "Text '2021-11-24T13:14:47.497' could not be parsed at index 23"

So seems like the date format in my records can't be parsed by elastic.

Just wanted to know if there was any other way I can do it. If not I guess I will have to manually reindex the information from a script but that would take some time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're after is this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

If you decide to go the script route it shouldn't be too hard, you simply want to

```
1. pull all the existing docs
2. store them in a list 
3. iterate over and correct your timestamps
4. delete original docs # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html
5. ingest your new docs with corrected timestamps
```